# CSS: giving precedence to class applied to TR over styling applied TD (tables)

Tags: css

Is there a way for the class applied to the TR element of a table to override the styling applied to the TD?

```
td {
    border: 1px dotted #d6d6d6;
}

.tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000 important;
}
```

In the above CSS code, what should I do so that the .tr class (applied to certain TR elements) overrides the td styling?

Comment: `.tr td` has higher specificity, you also don't need the `!important` (which also has a typo since its missing the !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the corrected CSS code to override the styling applied to the `td`:

```
td {
    border: 1px dotted #d6d6d6;
}

.tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `border-bottom` is more specific than `border` property. So, without using a class simply you could use `td` again and it would still work and override.

```css
td{
    border: 1px dotted #d6d6d6;
}

td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="tr">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```